# Number of possible combinations with a constraint

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I have a set of elements $\mathcal{P}$ of dimension $2N$. I imagine $\mathcal{P}$ as a collection of pairs, e.g. for $N=2$

$$
\mathcal{P}:=\{\underbrace{a_1,a_2}_{\text{pair}}, b_1, b_2\}
$$

---

I want to construct all the possible unordered collections of $k\leq 2N$ elements from $\mathcal{P}$ such that

(1) there are no repetitions

(2) if an element of a pair is included, the other is excluded

Continuing the example above:  for $k=2$ the collections are
$$
\{a_1,b_1\}, \{a_1,b_2\}, \{a_2,b_1\}, \{a_2,b_2\}
$$
for $k=3,4$ there are no collections

for $k=1$ the collections are 
$$
\{a_1\}, \{a_2\}, \{b_1\}, \{b_2\}
$$
How many collections are there for any generic $N$ and $k$?

Comment: I'm confused., what about $\{a_1\},\{a_2\},\{b_1\},\{b_2\}$ and $\emptyset$.  Are these not also sets which satisfy the conditions of "no repititions" and "if an element of a pair is included the other is excluded"?  You didn't specify that $k$ must be precisely two in your example.  If that was the case that you forgot to specify $k=2$ then would $k=1$ be the four nonempty sets I pointed out at the beginning?  Or are you requiring one of every pair be used?

Comment: Regardless... if you allow any value of $k$... pick which $k$ "letters" are used, then for each "letter" pick which "number" is used for it.  It is ambiguous whether $N$ is the number of pairs or the number of elements since you seem to have gone back and forth between the two... letting $N$ be the number of pairs, you would have $\binom{N}{k}2^k$ collections of size $k$

Comment: Thanks, I have edited my question to clarify the points you pointed out.